# Create jQuery tabs dynamically from menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsp

Kinda new to JSP and jQuery, so this question may seem a bit basic - however I searched and could't find a good solution.
I am trying to get a JSP page to load tabs dynamically from a menu - found lots of examples on the web but they load the tabs from the push of a button. What I have so far is this:

Welcome.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="main.mp2.util.UtilConstants, java.util.LinkedList" %>
<% String jsp = (String) request.getAttribute(UtilConstants.JSP_FILE);

%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.lightbox_me.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery-ui.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/TreeMenu.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/javascript.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="body_page">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="content_menu">
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li class="title">Main menu</li>
                        <li><a href="#!/Welcome" id="add_welcome_tab">Main</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!/Applications" id="add_applications_tab">Applications</a>
                    </ul>
                    <script type="text/javascript">make_tree_menu('menu');</script>
                </div>
                <div id="content_area">
                    <div id="tabs">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#tabs-1"><%=jsp.substring(jsp.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, jsp.lastIndexOf("."))%></a> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="tabs-1">
                            <jsp:include page="Welcome.jsp" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

javascrips.js

```
$(function() {
    var tabTemplate = "<li><a href='\#{href}'>\#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
    tabCounter = 2;
    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();

    // functions to create tabs for each menu type
    //menu-item Welcome
    $(document).on('click', '#add_welcome_tab', function() {
        var label = "Welcome",
        id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
        li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label)),
        tabContentHtml = "Welcome";
        tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
        tabs.append("<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>");
        tabs.tabs("refresh");
        tabCounter++;
    });

    //menu-item Applications
    $(document).on('click', '#add_applications_tab', function() {
        var label = "Applications",
        id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
        li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label)),
        tabContentHtml = "Applications";
        tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
        tabs.append("<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>");
        tabs.tabs("refresh");
        tabCounter++;
    });

    // close icon: removing the tab on click
    tabs.delegate("span.ui-icon-close", "click", function() {
        var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
        $("#" + panelId).remove();
        tabs.tabs("refresh");
    });

    tabs.bind("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.altKey && event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE) {
            var panelId = tabs.find(".ui-tabs-active").remove().attr("aria-controls");
            $("#" + panelId).remove();
            tabs.tabs("refresh");
        }
    });
});
```

The jQuery tabs' code was taken from http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation and it's working on a non-JSP page, but on mine it only loads all on the same tab. I can guess that the issue might be on where I have the `<jsp:include page="<%=jsp%>" />`, but I have no clue to where I should put it. Any thoughts?

PS: first question here :)

**EDIT1:** I managed to get the tabs appearing, but now I wanted to load each JSP file's contents inside all of them, not just the first one... thoughts?

Comment: Wow, I see it's the firs question! Please only post the relevant code. And read this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks, tried to clean it up a bit and leave the most relevant parts, although I'm not sure it that was enough...